# Concatenate tensors with different shapes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, tensor, shapes

I am new to tensorflow and I'm trying to concatenate 2 tensors with different shapes.
The tensors have shape:

```
>>> a
# <tf.Tensor: id=38, shape=(30000, 943, 1), dtype=float64

>>> b
<tf.Tensor: id=2, shape=(30000, 260, 1), dtype=float64
```

Is it possible to concatenate them on axis=0 to obtain a tensor with shape (60000, ?, 1)?
I tried to convert them to ragged tensors before concatenating:

```
a2 = tf.ragged.constant(a)
b2 = tf.ragged.constant(b)

c = tf.concat([a2, b2], axis=0)
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the tensor to [`RaggedTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor) then use your own code ([`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)).

```
a = tf.random.uniform((30000, 943, 1), maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)
b = tf.random.uniform((30000, 260, 1), maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)

rag_a = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(a)
rag_b = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(b)

res = tf.concat([rag_a, rag_b], axis=0)
print(res.shape)
```

---

```
(60000, None, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tf.ragged.stack` and `merge_dims` without converting them to ragged tensors:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a2 = tf.random.normal((10, 943, 1))
b2 = tf.random.normal((10, 260, 1))

c = tf.ragged.stack([a2, b2], axis=0).merge_dims(0, 1)
print(c.shape)

# (20, None, 1)
```